# Universal binary build using 10.4sdk is not working in 10.3.9?

Tags: objective-c

I have build an universal binary with xcode 2.4 using sdk10.4 on Mac 10.4.4, when I'm trying to invoke the application in 10.3.9 PPC machine,the application is not getting invoked, saying it is not able to find the libcurl.3.dylib.

Since 10.3.9 has only libcurl.2.dylib the application is not getting invoked?

But according to Universal binary definition, the universal binary build using 10.4sdk should run in the MAC OS prior to 10.4?

What am I missing? Y my application is trying to load libcurl.3.dylib instead of libcurl.2.dylib?
(FYI: In the xcode.proj I'm linking libcurl.dylib, which is the alias name for libcurl

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but "Universal" means the binary can run on different processors (x86, PowerPC), but it does not mean it can run on earlier versions of Mac OS. [This article](http://www.zengobi.com/blog/2006/03/details-on-our-universal-binary-port.html) gives details on building a "Universal" binary that can also run on Mac OS X 10.3.